# build nuxtjs with babel-node and babel 7

Tags: javascript, express, babeljs, nuxt.js

I'm working on a nuxtjs project with express,
in my back end I'm using all es6 features and rendering them with babel-node and babel 7.

on development environment or testing environment (ava) I've managed to run my project with babel 7 and babel node

but when I'm trying to build and run my server in production mode (nuxt build) from some reason all my back end URL routes returns 404 with the following error

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (/Users/elonsalfati/devel/misc/astralink/painter/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/Users/elonsalfati/devel/misc/astralink/painter/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12)
    at Unzip.handleStreamEnd (/Users/elonsalfati/devel/misc/astralink/painter/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:201:11)
    at Unzip.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1081:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

  statusCode: 500,
  name: 'NuxtServerError'
```

---

```
/*
  - createError.js:16 createError
    [painter]/[axios]/lib/core/createError.js:16:15

  - settle.js:18 settle
    [painter]/[axios]/lib/core/settle.js:18:12

  - http.js:201 Unzip.handleStreamEnd
    [painter]/[axios]/lib/adapters/http.js:201:11

  - events.js:187 Unzip.emit
    events.js:187:15

  - _stream_readable.js:1081 endReadableNT
    _stream_readable.js:1081:12

  - next_tick.js:63 process._tickCallback
    internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19
```

I only assume it's because of the babel thing that can't complete the rendering or is there another way I should render nuxt if I'm using express?

---

This is my `nuxt.config.js`

```
const pkg = require('./package')

const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',

  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' }
    ]
  },

  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#8bc34a' },

  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
    'vuetify/src/stylus/main.styl'
  ],

  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
    '@/plugins/vuetify'
  ],

  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios'
  ],
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  */
  axios: {
    // See https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#options
  },

  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {
      if (ctx.isServer) {
        config.externals = [
          nodeExternals({
            whitelist: [/^vuetify/]
          })
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "painter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "JS Painter",
  "author": "Elon Salfati",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server --exec babel-node",
    "build": "npm run test && nuxt build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production nuxt start",
    "build-start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm run build && npm run start",
    "test": "nyc ava --verbose"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-sanitizer": "^1.0.4",
    "firebase": "^5.0.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.12.1",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "nuxt": "^1.4.1",
    "vue-color": "^2.4.6",
    "vuetify": "^0.17.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/preset-stage-0": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "ava": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5",
    "nyc": "^12.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "supertest": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "ava": {
    "require": [
      "@babel/register",
      "@babel/polyfill"
    ]
  }
}
```

and finally my `.babelrc` file

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env", {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/preset-stage-0",
      {
        "decoratorsLegacy": true
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```